# Can not execute my NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java-6

I am doing a project in NetBeans with Java 6.

Going to project properties, sources I have there JDK 6, but in libraries, Java platform the JDK 1.8.

So I clean and build the project the I go to the dist folder and execute the .jar and it works. But when I move it to another computer it reports me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJD8C.jpg).

The other computer, where it doesn't work, doesn't have NetBeans installed but it has Java 6.0.22. It doesn't have the option to update Java because is in a network without the possibility for that.

Also the other PC can't execute with CMD, because it's blocked by the admin, same as .exe or .bat, but I can in mine.

I'm only using one main-class for testing the execution with a JCIFS library.

What I'm missing? If you need some extra information, sources or something, comment and I'll update.

**UPDATE**

Here is the manifest.mf of the .jar after building the project.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.7
Created-By: 1.8.0_121-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/jcifs-1.3.18.jar lib/xmlunit-core-2.3.0.jar lib/xmluni
 t-legacy-2.3.0.jar lib/xmlunit-matchers-2.3.0.jar lib/commons-io-2.5.
 jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: conectarsamba.ConectarSamba
```

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is compiled to be run by Java 8 since that is what you have.  Selecting Java 6 merely changes the source code compatibility options.

You will need JDK 6 to compile your project if you want to run it on Java 6

Comment: Then I need JDK 1.6? And how do I change it because I've changed it for the JDK 1.6 but when I build it, in the manifest- Created-by: 1.8.0.

Comment: Recreate the manifest / project.  Make sure you use the JDK 1.6 as your Java Platform

Comment: Ok I was checking the other PC, and seems that instead of using java for opening the jar it's using one of Microsoft. It could be this the problem, but I can't change the default opening program or the .reg.

Comment: And I created a new project from 0 using JDk 1.6 by default, and in the manifest keep appearing 1.8